# jQuery .parent() select multiple levels up

Tags: jquery, parent

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
<search>
    <inner>
        <input/>
        <p/>
        <img/>
    </inner>
</search>
```

What I am trying to do is to select the parent `<search>` of the `<input/>` onFocus, but if I do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
        console.log($(this).parent("search"));
    });
});
```

The console shows an empty array. Is there a clean way to select a parent more than one level up? The only way I know of to do this would be `.parent().parent("search")`, which would work, but is not very clean, and if I were trying to select a parent 5 tiers up, would be just atrocious.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$(this).closest("search")
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/parent/):

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Try using `$.parents` instead.